# NodeJS DES ECB encryption of hex data with module 'crypto'

Tags: node.js, encryption, cryptography, cryptojs, des

I am trying to **encrypt/decrypt hex data** using **node js module 'crypto'** with **DES-ECB algorithm**. In the official 'crypto' documentation, they give an example of aes-192 encryption in CBC mode (cf attached code) but **with the ECB mode no iv (initilization vector) is needed**. I don't know how to adapt this code to encrypt in ECB mode with the DES algorithm.

Here's the JavaScript code given in the official documentation of node js 'crypto' module (https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v10.x/docs/api/crypto.html#crypto_class_cipher):

```
const crypto = require('crypto');

const algorithm = 'aes-192-cbc';
const password = 'Password used to generate key';
// Key length is dependent on the algorithm. In this case for aes192, it is
// 24 bytes (192 bits).
// Use async `crypto.scrypt()` instead.
const key = crypto.scryptSync(password, 'salt', 24);
// Use `crypto.randomBytes()` to generate a random iv instead of the static iv
// shown here.
const iv = Buffer.alloc(16, 0); // Initialization vector.

const cipher = crypto.createCipheriv(algorithm, key, iv);

let encrypted = '';
cipher.on('readable', () => {
  let chunk;
  while (null !== (chunk = cipher.read())) {
    encrypted += chunk.toString('hex');
  }
});
cipher.on('end', () => {
  console.log(encrypted);
  // Prints: e5f79c5915c02171eec6b212d5520d44480993d7d622a7c4c2da32f6efda0ffa
});

cipher.write('some clear text data');
cipher.end();
```

In my case I have to change the "algorithm" field to:

```
const algorithm = 'des-ecb'
```

But then I also have to adapt the parts dealing with the iv (as no iv is needed with DES-ECB algorithm) and I don't know how to do that...

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Is there a specific reason to use DES that is no more secure and ECB which is also not secure mode? Also,see [this](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v10.x/docs/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_createcipher_algorithm_password_options)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this approach, this should do what you want:

```
const crypto = require('crypto');
const algorithm = 'des-ecb';
// use a hex key here
const key = Buffer.from("d0e276d0144890d3", "hex");

const cipher = crypto.createCipheriv(algorithm, key, null);
let encrypted = cipher.update("Those are my principles, and if you don't like them... well, I have others.", 'utf8', 'hex');
encrypted += cipher.final('hex');
console.log("Encrypted: ", encrypted);

const decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv(algorithm, key, null);
let decrypted = decipher.update(encrypted, 'hex', 'utf8');
decrypted += decipher.final('utf8');
console.log("Decrypted: ", decrypted);
```

Comment: Ok, thank you very much @TerryLennox, it works!

One last thing do you know how to choose my own hex key instead of letting the crypto function generating one out of the password I gave? Thanks!

Comment: Hey @LFO, just choose a strong key, make sure it's not guessable, ideally it should be cryptographically strong pseudo-random data. You can use const key = crypto.randomBytes(8) for this purpose.

Comment: I get it, thanks again @TerryLennox ! in fact I receive some data from GPS trackers. This data is encrypted with a hex key that the supplier gave me so I can't use a random key to decrypt/encrypt the data, I need to use this specific key but I don't find how to do that...

Comment: The key is a Buffer, so we can do this: e.g. const key = Buffer.from("d0e276d0144890d3", "hex"); Just replace the sample hex data with yours!

Comment: Ok, this helps me a lot for my project, thank you very much @TerryLennox, have a good day!